# Does the "content-management" tag have any meaning, for Drupal?

Tags: discussion, tags

I notice there are questions tagged [content-management](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-management), but I don't understand in which cases the tag should apply, considering that Drupal is a CMS, and the content management aspect of it is predominant (otherwise Drupal would not be a CMS).

Is there any better tag to use instead of [content-management](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-management), or should the tag simply removed?

I am wondering about the tag because the questions using it.

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25629/i-need-to-upload-several-hundreds-of-pdfs-at-once-and-allow-these-files-to-be-a
- [Manage Display of Entity Reference Field: How to link to nodes instead of plain-text?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23734/manage-display-of-entity-reference-field-how-to-link-to-nodes-instead-of-plain)
- [Linking Custom Content Types Together](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23683/linking-custom-content-types-together)
- [Is there a way to limit how much storage users have to store their content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22028/drupal-7-storage-limit)
- [Are there existing modules to group nodes and give sequential access to them in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21038/are-there-existing-modules-to-group-nodes-and-give-sequential-access-to-them-in)
- [Can I use views_bulk_operations with the D7 core toolbar module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/can-i-use-views-bulk-operations-with-the-d7-core-toolbar-module)

As you see, the newest questions are using the tag in a too generic way. If that is the way of using the tag, then Drupal is all about content management, and the tag is quite too bread to be useful. If the tag has a specific meaning, then there are questions using the tag that should not be using it; if that is the case, the tag should be removed from some of the questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mostly agree with @Clive, but need a little more space to address @kiamlaluno's comment.

If we ignore how the tags currently being used, based on experience with clients, the concepts of content and content management are two very different things, and are often done by different user groups.  Using the same tag would potentially results in it being used for two classes of questions.

To put it in Drupal terms, I would say that content is more about the daily tasks of making nodes, editing, etc, and potentially the UX/IA that surrounds this.

I would say that content management is more about issues sucks as workflow, revisioning, import, content staging, and similar tasks.  And frankly, these are the tasks that are either clunky or just plain don't work well in Drupal.

If a distinction is made about how tags *should* be used, I think it could lead to better organization of questions on the site.

Comment: +1 well said that's pretty much exactly what I was trying to get across but my friday brain wasn't having it :)

Comment: The problem is exactly how the tag is currently used. It is used in completely different questions, and with a too broad meaning. If that is the case, then every questions about Drupal should use it, as Drupal is a CMS. Any operation made on the content is about content management, including handling users, as there isn't content without users.

Comment: The first question mentioned by @kiamlaluno is clearly a `content management` issue, but the last two are more of the `site-building`. However, outside of Drupal-land, I have never seen the term `site builiding`, maybe that's why new users might misuse `content management`. It *is* a hot word. Should we just ban it?

Answer (score 2):

I see Drupal as a framework rather than a CMS these days, and as such I'd say [content-management](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-management) is simply one *aspect* of that framework. To my mind it would be on a par with a tag called [user-management](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-management) (which doesn't actually exist but in my opinion would be perfectly valid).

A question tagged [content-management](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-management) could conceivably be something such as *"What is the best method for allowing different users to manage their own content within a Drupal site?"*.

I think the tag would be perfectly valid in an instance like that.

Just my two cents as always :)